# Como exibir uma imagem na tela diretamente do banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql

Boa tarde! Estou trabalhando nesse trecho de código de um sistema maior e esse trecho não está exibindo a imagem na tela. O código em teoria seleciona a coluna vImageDeliveryPref da tabela orders no banco de dados e verifica se há algum resultado, se houver, ele mostra a imagem na página, mas tem alguma coisa errada q a imagem não tá aparecendo. Segue o trecho de código:

```
<?php $result = $conn->query("SELECT vImageDeliveryPref FROM orders WHERE iCompanyId = 2591"); ?>
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
<?php $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); ?>
<?php $caminho_imagem = $row['vImageDeliveryPref']; ?>
<?php $URLbase = 'http://isteel.com.br/webimages/upload/order_delivery_pref/' . $caminho_imagem ?>
<img src="<?= $URLbase ?>">
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo "A imagem ainda não foi tirada."; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Essa foi a forma que eu encontrei de escrever o código sem que a página ficasse quebrando. Sabem me ajudar com isso por favor?

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145775/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-hsl-como-exibir-uma-imagem-na-tela-diretamente). Quem quiser ler ou participar, utilize o link fornecido. Para viabilizar a postagem, queira [edit] trocando o trecho de código por um [mcve] do problema (indispensável nesse caso - clique no link para ver os requisitos). A [help] pode ajudar a entender o funcionamento deste site.